# Google Web Toolkit Dump All Request And Response

Tags: java, web-services, gwt, java-ee-7

I have one old app, developed using Google Web Toolkit, I can not find a way to dump all(HTTP) request made to it and all response (HTTP) send from it.

The app is deployed using TomCat 9.
I tried dumping all request and response to TomCat, but, it is not helping.

How I can dump all HTTP requests made to my App and all HTTP responses sent from my App?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the tomcat access log files, such as `CATALINA_HOME/logs/localhost_access_log.DATE.txt`.  You will see (among other things) all HTTP request URLs and the HTTP response code from the server.  E.g.

```
192.168.0.105 - - [29/Apr/2020:15:14:49 +1000] "POST /RecvQueService/lookupRailQue HTTP/1.1" 401 988
192.168.0.105 - - [29/Apr/2020:15:14:58 +1000] "GET /MossmanReceivalsMimic/YardMimic.html?mode=operator HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```